# Excel drop down shows all options in just one line as one single comma separated option

Tags: excel, vba, dropdown

I've created a drop down list through VBA. sometimes it shows all options as on single option.
sometimes switching between sheets fix the problem, sometimes not!
Here is the code:

```
Dim arr1(8) As String
    arr1(0) = "EURUSD"
    arr1(1) = "GBPUSD"
    arr1(2) = "USDCHF"
    arr1(3) = "USDJPY"
    arr1(4) = "USDCAD"
    arr1(5) = "AUDUSD"
    arr1(6) = "NZDUSD"
    arr1(7) = "XAUUSD"

With Range("C" & 1).Validation
    .Delete
    .Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, Operator:=xlBetween, Formula1:=Join(arr1, ",")
End With
```

I appreciate any help with this issue.

[image: Drop down list mixed up all options]

Comment: You don't need `Operator:=xlBetween` here. Though I can't reproduce this behavior. What is the size of `arr1`?

Comment: **[1.]** How are you declaring and initializing the array. Can you include that code in the above question as well so that we can see a minimal reproducible example? **[2.]** Where are you running the code from?

Comment: I've added the declaration to the code.

Comment: I removed Operator:=xlBetween, but it didn't fixed the problem.
Actually I have 3 different arrays with length of 31, 8, 4

Comment: I am unable to reproduce the issue. It works just fine for me. Where are you calling the code from?

Comment: I am calling the code from Worksheet_Activate

Comment: I tested the code in your question from `Worksheet_Activate` event and it works just fine

Comment: I've also noticed when I'm using data validation option from data tab and put data manually in the "source: field (e.g. "Yes, No"), the problem still exist, but when I use a range as source it works fine. So, I think this problem has nothing to do with VBA.

Comment: `and put data manually in the "source: field (e.g. "Yes, No"), the problem still exist` What happens if you use `Yes;No` instead of `Yes, No`

Comment: If the above works then also try `Formula1:=Join(arr1, Application.International(xlListSeparator))` instead of `Formula1:=Join(arr1, ",")`

Comment: I tried "Yes; No", The result is the same "Yes; No

Comment: Formula1:=Join(arr1, Application.International(xlListSeparator)) 
Fixed The Problem. Thank you so much Siddhartah

Comment: Posted an answer. In VBE, type `?Application.International(xlListSeparator)`. You wil know what is the list separator. You can then use that in `"Yes;No"` instead of `;` or `,` to check while manually adding the DV List

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like the `List Separator` setting (*Control Panel | Regional Options*) is something other than a `Comma (,)`. For example, if your locale setting is Germany, then I guess your list separator would be a `Semicolon (;)`. In VBE, type `?Application.International(xlListSeparator)` to quickly check what is your `List Separator`.

If you are doing it manually from the `Data` Tab then use the correct `List Separator`. For example `YES;NO`

If you are doing it via VBA then use `Application.International(xlListSeparator)`

In your code replace `Formula1:=Join(arr1, ",")` with `Formula1:=Join(arr1, Application.International(xlListSeparator))`

Comment: Thank u so much Siddharth
btw is there any thank button in the site?

Comment: There is an upvote button but you need enough reputation to click it. :)  FYI [Help Center > Privileges > Vote up](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-up)